# substitution within a text file, using Applescript and sed

Tags: sed, applescript

The question is a sequel to [plain text URL to HTML code (Automator/AppleScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670756/plain-text-url-to-html-code-automator-applescript).

Suppose I have a plain txt file /Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt:

```
title 1
http://a.b/c

title 2
http://d.e/f

...
```

I'd like to (1) convert all the URL (http://...) to HTML code, and (2) add

```
&nbsp;<br />
```

to each empty line, so that the aforementioned content will become:

```
title 1
<a href="http://a.b/c">http://a.b/c</a>
&nbsp;<br />
title 2
<a href="http://d.e/f">http://d.e/f</a>
&nbsp;<br />
...
```

I come to the following Applescript:

```
set inFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt"
set middleFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist2.txt"
set outFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist3.txt"

do shell script "sed 's/\\(http[^ ]*\\)/<a href=\"\\1\">\\1<\\/a>/g' " & quoted form of inFile & " >" & quoted form of middleFile
do shell script "sed 's/^$/\\&nbsp;<br \\/>/g' " & quoted form of middleFile & " >" & quoted form of outFile
```

It works, but it is redundant (and silly?). Could anyone make it more succinct? Can it be done involving only one text file instead of three (i.e. the original content in /Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt is overwritten with the end result)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: +1 for model sample question, with sample input, required output and sample code (gasp). Keep posting and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set inFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt"

set myData to (do shell script "sed '
/\\(http[^ ]*\\)/ a\\
&nbsp;<br />
' " & quoted form of inFile & " | sed 's/\\(http[^ ]*\\)/<a href=\"\\1\">\\1<\\/a>/g' ")

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myData & " > " & quoted form of inFile
```

This will let you use the myData variable later in your script. If this is not part of a larger script and you are simply modifying your file, use the -i option as jackjr300 suggests. Also, this script looks for the original pattern and appends the new line to it rather than simply looking for empty lines.

EDIT:

```
set inFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt"
set myData to (do shell script "sed 's/\\(http[^ ]*\\)/<a href=\"\\1\">\\1<\\/a>/g; s/^$/\\&nbsp;<br \\/>/g' " & quoted form of inFile)
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myData & " > " & quoted form of inFile
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is logically different from what I asked for. In fact, the real text file that I'd like to process is more complicated than the aforementioned sample input (involving some quoted sentences, for example). (By the way, your code, unlike the other two answers, does not have the problem of text encoding. I don't know why....)

Comment: I thought you wanted &nbsp;<br /> to follow each URL. For every blank line see my edited version.

Comment: I'm sorry for having not clarified it enough.... For your edited version, I guess what you mean is: **line 1** 

    `set inFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt"`
**line 2**     `set myData to (do shell script "sed 's/\\(http[^ ]*\\)/<a href=\"\\1\">\\1<\\/a>/g; s/^$/\\&nbsp;<br \\/>/g' " & quoted form of inFile)`
**line 3**     `do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myData & " > " & quoted form of inFile`

To the second line I added `set myData to (` at the beginning and `\\\` before the first &.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yup ... copied it too quickly. I updated the EDITED version to the correct script.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-i ''` option to edit ﬁles in-place.

```
set inFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.txt"

do shell script "sed -i '' 's:^$:\\&nbsp;<br />:; s:\\(http[^ ]*\\):<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>:g' " & quoted form of inFile
```

If you want a copy of the original file, use a speciﬁed extension like `sed -i ' copy'`

--
Updated:

A `DOCTYPE is a required preamble.
DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant specifications.

The HTML lang attribute can be used to declare the language of a Web page or a portion of a Web page. This is meant to assist search engines and browsers. According to the W3C recommendation you should declare the primary language for each Web page with the lang attribute inside the `<html>` tag

The `<meta>` tag provides metadata about the HTML document. `<meta>` tags always goes inside the `<head>` element.
The `http-equiv` attribute provides an HTTP header for the information/value of the content attribute.
`content`: the value associated with the `http-equiv` or name attribute.
`charset`: To display an **HTML** page correctly, the browser must know what character-set to use.

In this script: I put "**utf-8**" as encoding, change it by the encoding of your original file.

```
set inFile to "/Users/myname/Desktop/URLlist.html" -- text file with a ".html" extension
set nL to linefeed
set prepandHTML to "<!DOCTYPE html>\\" & nL & "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en-US\" lang=\"en-US\">\\" & nL & tab & "<head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\\" & nL & "</head>\\" & nL

do shell script "sed -i '' 's:^$:\\&nbsp;<br />:; s:\\(http[^ ]*\\):<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>:g; 1s~^~" & prepandHTML & "~' " & quoted form of inFile
do shell script "echo '</html>' " & quoted form of inFile -- write last HTML tag
```

Comment: Functional and succinct. Thank you. The only problem is that the new URLlist.txt cannot be opened in Finder by double-clicking it (but it can be opened by dragging its icon to Safari/Firefox). How can I fix that?

Comment: To open a document by double-clicking, save your document with the "**.html**" extension instead of "**.txt**".
 A `HTML` document is not as simple as you think, you must specify a  DOCTYPE, Namespaces (xmlns, xml:lang, lang) and Meta (http-equiv, content, **charset**) to display correctly in a browser.
Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand sed commands very well (it makes my brain hurt) so here's the applescript way to do this task. Hope it helps.

```
set f to (path to desktop as text) & "URLlist.txt"

set emptyLine to "&nbsp;<br />"
set htmlLine1 to "<a href=\""
set htmlLine2 to "\">"
set htmlLine3 to "</a>"

-- read the file into a list
set fileList to paragraphs of (read file f)

-- modify the file as required into a new list
set newList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of fileList
    set thisItem to item i of fileList
    if thisItem is "" then
        set end of newList to emptyLine
    else if thisItem starts with "http" then
        set end of newList to htmlLine1 & thisItem & htmlLine2 & thisItem & htmlLine3
    else
        set end of newList to thisItem
    end if
end repeat

-- make the new list into a string
set text item delimiters to return
set newFile to newList as text
set text item delimiters to ""

-- write the new string back to the file overwriting its contents
set openFile to open for access file f with write permission
write newFile to openFile starting at 0 as text
close access openFile
```

***EDIT***: if you have trouble with the encoding these 2 handlers will handle the read/write properly. So just insert them in the code and adjust those lines to use the handlers. Good luck.

***NOTE***: when opening the file using TextEdit, use the File menu and open specifically as UTF-8.

```
on writeTo_UTF8(targetFile, theText, appendText)
    try
        set targetFile to targetFile as text
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile with write permission
        if appendText is false then
            set eof of openFile to 0
            write «data rdatEFBBBF» to openFile starting at eof -- UTF-8 BOM
        else
            tell application "Finder" to set fileExists to exists file targetFile
            if fileExists is false then
                set eof of openFile to 0
                write «data rdatEFBBBF» to openFile starting at eof -- UTF-8 BOM
            end if
        end if
        write theText as «class utf8» to openFile starting at eof
        close access openFile
        return true
    on error theError
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return theError
    end try
end writeTo_UTF8

on readFrom_UTF8(targetFile)
    try
        set targetFile to targetFile as text
        targetFile as alias -- if file doesn't exist then you get an error
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile
        set theText to read openFile as «class utf8»
        close access openFile
        return theText
    on error
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end readFrom_UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you.
The Applescript works, except that (1) some of the Chinese characters will become gibberish, (2) the new URLlist.txt cannot be opened in Finder by double-clicking it (but it can be opened by dragging its icon to Safari/Firefox.
Could the issue of text encoding be corrected?

Comment: Well you can just read/write the file as «class utf8» if that's an issue. I added an "edit section" to my post to give you handlers for doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your devoted time. Since adayzdone's script does not have the issue of text encoding, I am curious about the difference of handling text encoding between Applescript and sed.